# Export vuejs components to reuse

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component, vue-cli

I created an api. And for him, I created a one-page interface using vuecli. My plans are to embed it in the projects I need. The question is what needs to be done to export the written application and reuse it where necessary?

The structure of the project is shown in the screenshot.

[image]

- `src/main.js` - connect and configure axios
- `src/App.vue` - I describe the main component of the application
  (maybe I need to put it in a separate component in the components
  folder)
- `src/components/OneDay.vue` is the second component that is mainly
  called `src/App.vue` several times.
- `src/mixins/dateHandler.js` - several functions common to the two
  components, which are connected as mixins.

I have not modified any other files. How can I prepare this correctly so that I can connect these components to my other applications using composer? I connect, configure some variables (api address, for example) and display it in the right place on the page - this is how I see it.

Answer (score 4):

You can try to create a web component using VUE CLI 3 to use it later in a different code base. Just make sure your `main.js` file looks like this

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import wrap from '@vue/web-component-wrapper';
import VueWebComponent from './components/VueWebComponent';

const CustomElement = wrap(Vue, VueWebComponent);

window.customElements.define('my-custom-element', CustomElement);
```

and build it using `vue-cli-service build` with `--target wc`

You can read more precise instructions there:
https://github.com/vuejs/vue-web-component-wrapper
https://vuejsdevelopers.com/2018/05/21/vue-js-web-component/